# Unabel to define int variable in Enum before the values are defined

Tags: java, enums

I am sorry if this is answered before. I did a search but didn't find.Hi I tried to define my Enum as below which works fine.

```
public enum MyEnum {

    PRODUCT,STORE,PROMOTION,VOUCHER,URL;

    private int value;


}
```

but when I define it as below it **can not identify int token**. Why is that?

```
public enum MyEnum  {

    private int value;

    PRODUCT,STORE,PROMOTION,VOUCHER,URL;

}
```

Comment: And how do you access that value?

Comment: Note that this value will be defined for each enum constant; it is not a class variable. Not sure why you need to declare such a variable _after_ the enum constants declaration though...

Comment: @fge I am planning a add a constructor with int arg and set it to enum values.

Comment: Then this is not the way to do it ;) See my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) it says

> Java requires that the constants be defined first, prior to any fields or methods. Also, when there are fields and methods, the list of enum constants must end with a semicolon.

Answer (score 3):

The **enum** constants **must be declared before any other variables** and methods declaration in an enum type. If an enum declares only values in it, then semi-colon is optional. Otherwise, the semi-colon at the end of declared values is mandatory. For example, you need ";" at the end of BLUE("blue").

[What can or can not for the Java enum type when you use it?](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-can-or-can-not-for-the-java-enum-type-when-you-use-it/136)

Comment: Is this a quote? If it is consider adding a link.

Answer (score 2):

Addendum (the question is already answered, this is a howto): if you want to add a constructor to an enum, the arguments to the constructor must be attached to the enum constants themselves:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    VALUE1(1);

    private final int value;

    // Constructors of enums are private by default,
    // no need to specify the access modifier
    MyEnum(final int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Note that you can also add methods:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    VALUE1
    {
        @Override
        public int getValue()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    };

    public abstract int getValue();
}
```

And you can combine both; in this case, values are mentioned first, then method implementations, like in:

```
VALUE("foo", 32)
{
    @Override public int method1() { // whatever }
    @Override public String method2() { // whatever }
};
```

Comment: thanks dude. That is what I planned to do. Here is my +1 for you  though I accept the first answer from DevZero

Comment: @SanjayaLiyanage no problem ;) Enums are very powerful in Java.